# como aplicar clausula INCLUDE en una relacion belongsToMany Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, backend, sequelize

tengo la siguiente situación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una relacion de muchos a muchos, estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta a la tabla de union UserBuyAdventure:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que la consulta me traiga todos los registros y me incluya el modelo de aventura en cada registro, sin embargo al utilizar el include me genera error.

la consulta sin el "include" funciona perfect pero no me trae el modelo aventura.

Ayuda por favor, muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] y modifica tu pregunta reemplazando las imágenes de código por texto. Y añade lo que haga falta para poder reproducir la situación. Ten presente que debes ofrecer un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

listo ya lo solucione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cambie las relaciones, las tenia mal y el include ya funciona, lo hice asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener?

Por lo que veo en tu consulta quieres obtener BuyAdventure con todas sus Adventure.

Entonces, de ser así no se por qué haces un belongToMany entre Usuario y Adventure.

Tampoco se por qué es belongToMany si la relación de usuario con adventure es 1 a muchos y no muchos a muchos.

La otra duda es si también quieres los usuarios.